# Existence of $v$,$\lvert\lvert v \rvert\rvert = 1$, such that $\langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \lvert\lvert T \rvert \rvert^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $T : H \rightarrow H$ be a compact linear operator on a Hilbert space which is NOT necessarily self-adjoint. How would you prove that there exists $v \in H$, $\lvert\lvert v \rvert\rvert = 1$, such that $\langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \lvert\lvert T \rvert \rvert^2$ ?

I don't know how I should take on this problem. Of course, I can use the compacity assumption right at the beginning. But then, I'm lost.

Comment: What‘s the definition of the operator norm?

Comment: @Fakemistake supremum of $\lvert\lvert Tv \rvert\rvert$ over elements $v$ of norm less or equal to $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently my original answer (below) overlooked an important detail.

With that being said, we can reduce this question to the case of self-adjoint compact operators if we note that
$$
\langle Tv,Tv \rangle = \langle v, T^*Tv \rangle = \|\sqrt{T^*T}v\|^2
$$
and that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint and compact.

---

**Hint:** Consider the function $v \mapsto \|v\|^2$ as a continuous function restricted to the image of the closed unit ball under $T$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still cannot see how to do it. $T(\overline{B_1(0)})$ is only relatively compact so (for example) I cannot immediately conclude that the max of the function $v \mapsto \lvert\lvert v \rvert\rvert^2$ is attained.

Comment: @Desura ah, that is a problem.  I'll delete this answer if I can't think of a fix.

Comment: @Desura does that answer let you get the rest of the way?  If so, I'd like to know how

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Do you need to take a detour through functional calculus to define the square root?

Comment: @CameronWilliams it suffices to define the square root by power series.  Pedersen's *Analysis Now* uses something like that in his proof of the polar decomposition

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We have $\lvert\lvert T^*T \rvert \rvert = \lvert\lvert  T \rvert \rvert ^2$. Furthermore, $T^*T$ is compact, self-adjoint. One of the first step in proving Spectral Theorem in Functional Analysis is proving that if $Q$ is linear, compact, self-adjoint, then $\lvert \lvert Q \rvert \rvert = \sup \{ \lvert \langle Qv, v \rangle \rvert \mid \lvert\lvert v \rvert\rvert \leq 1 \}$ and either $\lvert\lvert Q \rvert\rvert$ or $-\lvert\lvert Q \rvert\rvert$ is an eigenvalue of $Q$. But it's not a proof I can do in the comment section.

Comment: @Desura that's plenty already, thanks for the gist.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah yeah true. I think Dixmier does something similar if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Take the weak topology on the unit ball. The mapping $v\mapsto \|Tv\|$ is continuous on the now compact ball. No need ofr heavy machinery.

Comment: @daw Very nice! Should have thought of that

Answer (score 2):

By definition of the operator norm, there is for each $n$ a vector $v_n$ with $\|v_n\|\le 1$ such that
$$
\|Tv \|\ge \|T\|-1/n.
$$
Hilbert spaces are reflexive, after extracting a subsequence if necessary we have $v_n\rightharpoonup v$ and (by compactness) $Tv_n\to Tv$. By weak lower semicontiuity of norms, $\|v\|\le1$. This shows $\|v\|\le1$ and $\|Tv\|=\|T\|$.
If $T\ne0$ this implies $v\ne0$ and scaling argument shows $\|v\|=1$.